# Query to show earliest & latest date, with the sum of values in 3rd column

Tags: sql

I have a table where it shows an Item #, then all the Enter & Exit dates when it goes into a certain workflow.  However I just need the first enter date and the last exit date, and all of the days elapsed to be aggregated. Below is the current table.

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ ENTERDATE  ║  EXITDATE  ║ DAYS ║  ITEMNO   ║    WORKFLOW     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 08/06/2012 ║ 08/09/2012 ║ 2.79 ║ 100004739 ║ 01 - VND Enrich ║
║ 08/21/2012 ║ 09/11/2012 ║ 21.2 ║ 100004739 ║ 01 - VND Enrich ║
║ 08/09/2012 ║ 08/13/2012 ║ 4.25 ║ 100004739 ║ 02 - DFM Review ║
║ 09/11/2012 ║ 09/13/2012 ║ 1.83 ║ 100004739 ║ 02 - DFM Review ║
║ 08/13/2012 ║ 08/16/2012 ║ 2.91 ║ 100004739 ║ 03 - QC 1       ║
║ 09/13/2012 ║ 09/14/2012 ║ 1    ║ 100004739 ║ 03 - QC 1       ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

I need to write a query to achieve the below:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ ENTERDATE  ║  EXITDATE  ║ DAYS  ║  ITEMNO   ║    WORKFLOW     ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 08/06/2012 ║ 09/11/2012 ║ 23.99 ║ 100004739 ║ 01 - VND Enrich ║
║ 08/09/2012 ║ 09/13/2012 ║ 6.08  ║ 100004739 ║ 02 - DFM Review ║
║ 08/13/2012 ║ 09/14/2012 ║ 3.91  ║ 100004739 ║ 03 - QC 1       ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Can anyone advise??

Comment: Please reformat your example table so it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MIN(EnterDate) MIN_EnterDATE,
        MAX(ExitDate) Max_ExitDate,
        SUM(days),
        ItemNo, WorkFlow
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY ItemNo, WorkFlow
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf844/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25eff/4)